# How to convent viewmodel to Expression<Func<T,bool>>?

Tags: c#, ienumerable, expression-trees, iqueryable, func

Piggybacking off of a [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26578303/how-to-convert-a-simple-viewmodel-to-funct-bool-predicate)...

I need to generate an *Expression* from a *ViewModel* to pass as a search predicate for `IQueryable.Where`. I need to be able to include/exclude query parameters based on what is provided by the user. Example:

```
public class StoresFilter
{
    public int[] Ids { get; set; }

    [StringLength(150)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [StringLength(5)]
    public string Abbreviation { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Show all")]
    public bool ShowAll { get; set; } = true;

    public Expression<Func<Store, bool>> ToExpression()
    {
        List<Expression<Func<Store, bool>>> expressions = new List<Expression<Func<Store, bool>>>();

        if (Ids != null && Ids.Length > 0)
        {
            expressions.Add(x => Ids.Contains(x.Id));
        }
        if (Name.HasValue())
        {
            expressions.Add(x => x.Name.Contains(Name));
        }
        if (Abbreviation.HasValue())
        {
            expressions.Add(x => x.Abbreviation.Contains(Abbreviation));
        }
        if (!ShowAll)
        {
            expressions.Add(x => x.Enabled == true);
        }
        if (expressions.Count == 0)
        {
            return x => true;
        }

        // how to combine list of expressions into composite expression???
        return compositeExpression;
    }
}
```

Is there a simple way to build a composite expression from a list of expressions? Or do I need to go through the process of manually building out the expression using `ParameterExpression`, `Expression.AndAlso`,  `ExpressionVisitor`, etc?

Comment: As far as I understand you are looking for a way to generate the `Expression<Func<T,bool>>` at run time, which can be supplied to a `IQueryable<T>` where clause, it can be easily made a generic for any type `T`. Otherwise need to be coded for every type separately for type specific logic

Comment: Update the code for using the Sample model `Store` that you have provided, adding a code for all use cases you have mentioned

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should not build and combine `Expression`s, but instead of this you should do it through `IQuerable<Store>` via `.Where` chain. Moreover, `source.Expression` will contain desired expression:

```
public IQueryable<Store> ApplyFilter(IQueryable<Store> source)
{
    if (Ids != null && Ids.Length > 0)  
        source = source.Where(x => Ids.Contains(x.Id)); 

    if (Name.HasValue())    
        source = source.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(Name));  

    if (Abbreviation.HasValue())    
        source = source.Where(x => x.Abbreviation.Contains(Abbreviation));  

    if (!ShowAll)   
        source = source.Where(x => x.Enabled == true);      

    //or return source.Expression as you wanted
    return source;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
var filter = new StoresFilter { Name = "Market" };
var filteredStores = filter.ApplyFilter(context.Stores).ToList();
```

Comment: This is treating `IQueryable<T>` like `IEnumerable<T>` and replacing `Expression<Func<T>>` with `Func<T>`, which would work when all data is loaded in the memory, but in reality `IQueryable<T>` shall do the remote data processing, that's why Expression instead of plain Func. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793571/why-would-you-use-expressionfunct-rather-than-funct?rq=1) explains well.
For all data in memory IEnumerable<T> serves the purpose

Comment: @MrinalKamboj, can you concrete specify row, where it happen( _"treating"_)? Only `filteredStores` variable is `IEnumerable<Store>`, just because I called `.ToLIst()` method.

Comment: `IQueryable<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`, it is internally calling a MethodCallExpression , Check here https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/IQueryable.cs,965b3e30b9ed851f, for Linq methods like `Select`, `Where`, in this case it will be direct translation to Func<T>, nothing else is possible, since data is in memory and there's no Expression tree implementation it cannot be serialized to a remote data source to parse / execute to fetch data. This is correct in this context, but has limited application from Queryable context

Comment: @MrinalKamboj, why you decide, that data is already in memory? `context.Stores` is not in memory. Read question again: "to pass as a search predicate for IQueryable.Where", not IEnumerable.Where. Data only materialized after ToLIst() call. Where is conversion(impl/expl) to `Func<Store>` occurs, specify point.

Comment: @ SlavaUtesinov what kind of remote context is not clear from the question itself, creating Lambda based Expression is not always feasible / supported, especially if type metadata is not accessible. 
On other hand creating expressions through ExpressionTree classes would work in most of the cases. In my understanding there would be remote context where solution provided by you may not work as expected and would need explicit ExpressionTrees translation

Comment: @MrinalKamboj, kind of remote context doesn't matter. Real importance is that `source` implements `IQueryable<Store>`(read the question), so it always can build `Expression`s internally by itself via corresponding extention methods. At case of database, `Expression`s will be traslated to T-SQL, at case of `List<Store>`, it will be compiled to `Func<Store>`, we should not care about it, it is work of `IQueryProvider`. Your intention is correct, but it is too complicated and redundant.

Comment: By Remote Context I meant the implementation of the `IQueryable<Store>` for remote data processing, as many system are now supporting C# drivers, In Apache Ignite (Grid Gain), I have seen implementation of `ICacheQueryable<T>`, where they prefer to take Expression class object, as its easy to parse Metadata. In fact some of the `IQueryable<T>` methods contains `NotImplementedException`. In my understanding Expression class usage may be complex but provides much more control for data processing

Comment: @MrinalKamboj, It is endless dispute. Let OP decide.

Comment: No dispute from my end, your solution is certainly  simpler, provided the IQueryable<T> implementer is able to parse and create Expression internally

Answer (score 2):

```
void Main()
{
    var store = new Store
    {
      Id = 1,
      Abbreviation = "ABC",
      Enabled = true,
      Name = "DEF"
    };

   var filter =  new Filter<Store>
   {
    Ids = new HashSet<int>(new [] {1,2,3,4}),
    Abbreviation = "GFABC",
    Enabled = true,
    Name = "SDEFGH",
    ShowAll = false
   }

   var expression = filter.ToExpression(store);

   var parameterType = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Store), "obj");

   // Generate Func from the Expression Tree
   Func<Store,bool> func = Expression.Lambda<Func<Store,bool>>(expression,parameterType).Compile();
}

public class Store
{
    public int Id {get; set;}

    public string Name {get; set;}

    public string Abbreviation { get; set; }

    public bool Enabled { get; set; }   
}

public class Filter<T> where T : Store
{
    public HashSet<int> Ids { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Abbreviation { get; set; }

    public bool Enabled {get; set;}

    public bool ShowAll { get; set; } = true;

    public Expression ToExpression(T data)
    {
        var parameterType = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "obj");

        var expressionList = new List<Expression>();

        if (Ids != null && Ids.Count > 0)
        {
            MemberExpression idExpressionColumn = Expression.Property(parameterType, "Id");

            ConstantExpression idConstantExpression = Expression.Constant(data.Id, typeof(int));

            MethodInfo filtersMethodInfo = typeof(HashsetExtensions).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(HashSet<int>), typeof(int) });

            var methodCallExpression = Expression.Call(null, filtersMethodInfo, idExpressionColumn, idConstantExpression);

            expressionList.Add(methodCallExpression);
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name))
        {
            MemberExpression idExpressionColumn = Expression.Property(parameterType, "Name");

            ConstantExpression idConstantExpression = Expression.Constant(data.Name, typeof(string));

            MethodInfo filtersMethodInfo = typeof(StringExtensions).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string), typeof(string) });

            var methodCallExpression = Expression.Call(null, filtersMethodInfo, idExpressionColumn, idConstantExpression);

            expressionList.Add(methodCallExpression);
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Abbreviation))
        {
            MemberExpression idExpressionColumn = Expression.Property(parameterType, "Abbreviation");

            ConstantExpression idConstantExpression = Expression.Constant(data.Abbreviation, typeof(string));

            MethodInfo filtersMethodInfo = typeof(StringExtensions).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string), typeof(string) });

            var methodCallExpression = Expression.Call(null, filtersMethodInfo, idExpressionColumn, idConstantExpression);

            expressionList.Add(methodCallExpression);
        }
        if (!ShowAll)
        {
            MemberExpression idExpressionColumn = Expression.Property(parameterType, "Enabled");

            var binaryExpression = Expression.Equal(idExpressionColumn, Expression.Constant(true, typeof(bool)));

            expressionList.Add(binaryExpression);
        }

        if (expressionList.Count == 0)
        {
            expressionList.Add(BinaryExpression.Constant(true));
        }

        // Aggregate List<Expression> data into single Expression

        var returnExpression = expressionList.Skip(1).Aggregate(expressionList.First(), (expr1,expr2) => Expression.And(expr1,expr2));      

        return returnExpression;

        // Generate Func<T,bool> - Expression.Lambda<Func<T,bool>>(returnExpression,parameterType).Compile();
    }

}

public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static bool Contains(this string source, string subString)
    {
        return source?.IndexOf(subString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0;
    }
}

public static class HashsetExtensions
{
    public static bool Contains(this HashSet<string> source, string subString)
    {
        return source.Contains(subString,StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }
}
```

> How it works ?

- Only in simple equality cases you can use `BinaryExpression` like `Expression.Equal`, `Expression.GreaterThan`, which is shown for the property like "ShowAll"
- For other cases like `string / Array / List` Contains, you need extension method, which can take two types and provide the result. A separate `Contains` for string to make it case neutral. Also for collection `Hashset` has a better choice, it has O(1) time complexity, unlike O(N) for an array
- We use `MethodCallExpression` to call the extension methods
- Finally we aggreagte all the expressions, which can be compiled to create `Func<T,bool>`
- In case you need something like `x => true`, then `BinaryExpression.Constant(true)` is sufficient
- I have provided a Sample implementation using the Store class that you have defined

Comment: Downvoter mostly you don't understand the Expression trees, what I have mentioned is the correct way of custom processing Expression tree to generate `Function<T,bool>`